# Is it possible to add the in front of adjective for this case?

Tags: grammar

I learned that we use 'a' in this sentence like 'on a gloomy evening' and we should use 'article' in front of an adjective like gloomy, whereas we can use 'the' in the phrase like 'in the evening'.
If we write the sentence 'on a gloomy evening', can we write the sentence like 'on the gloomy evening to express specific evening?
Please, tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**evening** can refer to the time-of-day, or **evening** can refer to the night of a specific date when qualified with a date. The preposition **on** is used with dates, the preposition **in** with time-of-day.

> I went there **in** the gloomy evening. <sup>time of day</sup>
>
> I went there **on** the gloomy evening of March 27th. <sup>date</sup>

Without a specific date reference, you would not say **on the gloomy evening** except in a context where multiple evenings had been discussed, one of them a gloomy one, and you were referring specifically to the gloomy evening.

> Q. So, you visited that restaurant several times?
>    A. Yes, I had been there twice. Once with friends, celebrating, and once by
>   myself when I was feeling blue because of problems at work.
>    Q. And when did you meet the defendant?
>    A. I met him on the gloomy evening.

Comment: You would also use "the" if you're referring to all gloomy evenings in general: "In the gloomy evening, it's easy to believe that monsters are lurking in the shadows."

Comment: Yes indeed.....